# Problemas con menu en python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, pygame

Esto es lo que tengo

```
def Menu():
   #Muestra en pantalla la imagen guardada en Ganag
   screen.blit(Menug, (0,0))
   #Actualizará el contenido de la pantalla entera
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      dificultad =0
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      #"""if event.key==K_SPACE:
          #dificultad =1"""
      if event.key==K_ENTER: 
          dificultad = 2
   pygame.display.flip()
   pygame.time.delay(5000)
   exit()
```

y para llamarla hago esto

```
Fondo_Texto()
Menu()
if dificultad == 2:
   Tablero = TABLERO()
   #Guarda el resultado de Dar_Respuesta en solucion
   solucion = Dar_Respuesta()
   #Impreme la solucion
   print solucion
   #Se crea la variable Turno y se iguala a 0
```

Pero me da error como que dificultad esta definida pero no usada, que hago mal?

Parte completa:

```
import pygame, sys, os, random

from pygame.locals import *
#Inicia modo gráfico    
 pygame.init()
#Se crea la ventana y le damos un titulo
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((397,660))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mastermind!')
#Se asignan los colores a utilizar y los guardamos con sus nombres respectivos
Negro = (0,0,0)
Blanco = (255,255,255)
#A la fuente se le da un tipo de escritura y el tamaño
Fuente = pygame.font.SysFont('agencyfb', 24)
#Crea y guarda un nuevo objeto Clock que sirve para controlar el tiempo
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

dificultad =0
def Menu():
   global dificultad
   Nombre_Full = os.path.join('dibujo', 'Fondo_Menu4.png')
   Menug=pygame.image.load(Nombre_Full)
   #Muestra en pantalla la imagen guardada en Ganag
   screen.blit(Menug,(0,0))
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key==K_SPACE:
              dificultad =1
        #if event.key==K_ENTER: 
              #dificultad = 2
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(5000)              

#Carga las imagenes del juego en general data
def Cargar_Imagen(Nombre, colorkey=None): 
   #Carga y guarda las imagenes de la carpeta Diseño
   Nombre_Full = os.path.join('dibujo', Nombre)
  try:....
```

el resto son varias funciones y clases que declaro, y desde aqui empiezo (o intento) llamar a la funcion menu

```
#Menu general

#Carga y muestra el texto y la imagen de fondo

Menu()
Fondo_Texto()
#if dificultad == 2:
Tablero = TABLERO()
#Guarda el resultado de Dar_Respuesta en solucion
solucion = Dar_Respuesta()
#Impreme la solucion
print solucion
#Se crea la variable Turno y se iguala a 0
Turno = 0
#En tablero se cargan las casillas,los botonos de colores, las fichas y filas
Tablero.Casilla_Num()
Tablero.Color_Botones()
Tablero.Fichas()
Tablero.Fila_Selec()
#Calcula internamente cuantos milisegundos han transcurrido desde la llamada anterior.
Tiempo = clock.tick(10)
#Contador de los colores elegidos
Color_Num = 0
guessresult = []
#Nos da la posicion del mouse y la guarda en pos
pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
#Se le asignan los intentos y los turnos que ha realizado
if dificultad ==2:
   while Turno <= 15:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
       #Si el evento es igual a QUIT se cierra el juego
       if event.type == QUIT:
          sys.exit()
       #SI los turnos son iguales a los intentos permitidos, el jugador pierde    
       elif Turno == 15:
         #Le muestra una imagen diciendo que perdio
         Tablero.Pierde()
```

Lo que quiero hacer es guardar el numero de la opcion que elija el usuario y apartir de alli ejecutar la dificultad que pidio, ahora logre que me mostrara la imagen menu pero solo me la muestra por un tiempo, no me deja interactuar con ella y automaticamente despues pasa al juego... :(

Comment: La variable `dificultad` es local a la función `Menu`, esta variable deja de existir cuando la función retorna y no tiene efecto por tanto fuera de a misma (ni crea la vaariable ni la modifica si ya existe fuera de la función). Deberías especificar que se use la variable global con `global variable` en la función o mejor retornarla y hacer `dificultad = Menu()` . No obstante, ¿dónde llamas a `Menu`?¿Dentro del ciclo principal? Por otro lado, solo **compruebas el evento una vez** nada más llamar a la función, luego tienes el delay y terminas la ejecución con `exit`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es declarar la variable dificultad fuera de la función Menu y luego cambiarla usando `global` dentro de la función.

```
dificultad=0

def Menu():
   global dificultad
   #Muestra en pantalla la imagen guardada en Ganag
   screen.blit(Menug, (0,0))
   #Actualizará el contenido de la pantalla entera
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      dificultad=0
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      #"""if event.key==K_SPACE:
          #dificultad =1"""
      if event.key==K_ENTER: 
          dificultad=2
   pygame.display.flip()
   pygame.time.delay(5000)
   exit()
```

**Actualización:**

Para el otro problema, supongo que quieres que el usuario vea las opciones y si por ejemplo, presiona SPACE entonces, la dificultad cambie a 1 y de ahí, ejecute el código de esa dificultad, o lo mismo con la 2, no?

Bien, podrías hacer algo así:

Si la dificultad 0 es como la dificultad nula y quieres que el usuario elija una dificultad, podrías poner un bucle infinito hasta que la dificultad sea distinto de 0, que sería:

```
while(dificultad==0):
       for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==K_SPACE:
                    dificultad =1
                #if event.key==K_ENTER: 
                    #dificultad = 2
   pygame.display.flip() 
   pygame.time.delay(5000)
```

Si las dos últimas líneas se necesitan ejecutar en conjunto con el for, entonces nada más ponles la tabulación adecuada y listo, hasta que el usuario no elija su dificultad no se ejecutará el código de la dificultad correspondiente(? Si malinterpreté lo que querías decir, dime y busco la solución correcta

Comment: Gracias me funciono, ahora me podrias decir como hago para me ejecute el juego dependiendo de la opcion elegida por el usuario? :(

Comment: Sube la parte completa y dime dónde falla esa opción o al menos (?

Comment: Ya lo subi y trate de ser lo mas especifica posible, espero se entienda mejor :(

Comment: Actualizado, espero te sirva y sino, vuelve a comentar(?

Comment: MIL GRACIAS!!!! eso era lo que queria, ya podre darle los ultimos toques y enviarlo, muchas gracias de verdad!!! y disculpa las molestias , soy nueva en todo esto

Comment: No problem, estamos para ayudar, saludos y suerte! Cualquier nueva duda, ya sabes :)

Comment: Si tengo una... puse la otra dificultad pero cuando apreto espacio me sale este error "NameError: global name 'K_ENTER' is not defined"

Comment: Eso sería que la tecla K_ENTER no está definida en event.key, tal vez tienes o poner otra cosa o probar con otra tecla